# GLSL vertex shader gl_Position value

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I'm creating game that uses orthogonal view(2D). I'm trying to understand the value of `gl_Position` in vertex shader.

From what I understand `x` and `y` coordinates translate to screen position in range of -1 to 1, but I'm quite confused with role of the `z` and `w`, I only know that the `w` value should be set to `1.0`

For the moment I just use `gl_Position.xyw = vec3(Position, 1.0);`, where `Position` is 2D vertex position

I use OpenGL 3.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that openGL must also work for 3D and it's easier to expose the 3D details than to create a new interface for just 2D.

The Z component is to set the depth of the vertex, points outside -1,1 (after perspective divide) will not be drawn and for the values between -1,1 it will be checked against a depth buffer to see if the fragment is behind some previously drawn triangle and not draw it if it should be hidden.

The w component is for a perspective divide and allowing the GPU to interpolate the values in a perspective correct way. Otherwise the textures looks weird.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of depth need at this stage. Thanks for explaining!